# ¿Cómo puedo cargar un navbar con bootstrap-vue desde un array en vue?

Tags: php, array, bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Cordial saludo,

Estoy tratando de cargar un navbar desde una consulta que hago desde mi front, obtengo la cantidad de elementos del array perfectamente, pero los apuntadores no obtienen el nombre de los items y subitems, voy a dejar un ejemplo básico de lo que estoy tratando de hacer y la salida que obtengo:

Mi Array en vue:

```
rolesmultidimencional: [
    {
        padre_id: 1,
        padre_nombre: 'MENÚ 1',
        padre_hijos: [
            {
                nombre: 'Item1',
                clase: 'Ruta1'
            },
            {
              nombre: 'Item2',
              clase: 'Ruta2'
          }
        ]
    }, 
    {
      padre_id: 2,
      padre_nombre: 'MENÚ 2',
      padre_hijos: [
          {
              nombre: 'Item1',
              clase: 'Ruta3'
          },
          {
            nombre: 'Item2',
            clase: 'Ruta4'
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

Mi vista:

```
<div id="appNavbar">
    <div>
        <b-navbar type="dark" variant="dark">
            <b-navbar-nav>
                <div v-for="rol in rolesmultidimencional" :key="rol.padre_id">
                    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="rol.padre_nombre" right>
                        <div v-for="rolhijo in rol.padre_hijos" :key="rolhijo.clase">
                            <b-dropdown-item href="#">{rolhijo.nombre}</b-dropdown-item>
                        </div>
                    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
                </div>
            </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-navbar>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mi resultado:

[image: Vista por navegador y consola]

Comment: no tienes que hacer un loop/ciclo???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta bien la lógica pero para agregar una variable en el template es con llaves dobles {{}} y en el prop **text** cuando es dinamico se antepone -> : de esta manera:

```
<div id="appNavbar">
<div>
    <b-navbar type="dark" variant="dark">
        <b-navbar-nav>
            <div v-for="rol in rolesmultidimencional" :key="rol.padre_id">
                <b-nav-item-dropdown :text="rol.padre_nombre" right>
                    <div v-for="rolhijo in rol.padre_hijos" :key="rolhijo.clase">
                        <b-dropdown-item href="#">{{rolhijo.nombre}}</b-dropdown-item>
                    </div>
                </b-nav-item-dropdown>
            </div>
        </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-navbar>
</div>
```